# Bad superblock after server crash

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, raid, fsck

My server (CentOS 6) crashed, and it now kernel panics on boot. It's currently using a mdadm RAID1 array with two 1TB drives.

[image: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg_server2422-LogVol01]

- `vg_server2422-LogVol01` is /
- `vg_server2422-LogVol00` is Swap
- `vg_server2422-LogVol02` is the partition with all my data.

I have booted into a CentOS 6.3 LiveCD via. the Virtual Media, and I have run `lvscan`, which returns the volumes as active.

`fsck` says:

> The filesystem size (according to the superblock is 232603648 blocks
>
> The physical size of the device is 214958080 blocks
>
> Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!

If I don't abort it for LogVol02:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_server2422-LogVol02 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary informatoin
Error reading block 214958080 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading inode and block bitmaps. Ignore error<y>? yes

Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 214958080 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading inode and block bitmaps. Ignore error<y>? yes

Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 214958081 (Invalid argument) while reading inode and block bitmaps. Ignore error<y>? yes

Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 214958081 (Invalid argument) while reading inode and block bitmaps. Ignore error<y>? yes

Error reading block 215482368 (Invalid argument) while reading inode and block bitmaps. Ignore error<y>? yes

Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 215482368 (Invalid argument) while reading inode and block bitmaps. Ignore error<y>? yes

Error reading block 216006656 (Invalid argument) while reading inode and block bitmaps. Ignore error<y>? yes

Force rewrite<y>? yes

Error reading block 216006656 (Invalid argument) while reading inode and block bitmaps. Ignore error<y>?
```

...you get the idea. It continues for a long time. Trying to mount after that throws the same error (wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock). I've tried all of the SuperBlock backups with `fsck`, they all do not work.

Any ideas?

I followed one of the suggestions at [Recovering ext4 superblocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks) and ran `mke2fs -S -b 4096`, then `fsck`, however after a while `fsck` just crashed with "Segmentation Fault".

Comment: It probably would have been faster to just restore from backup