# Recover ext4 partition with bad superblock? (Failed after resizing, backup magic numbers don't work)

Tags: filesystems, partition, data-recovery, superblock

##### Background

Had a Linux root ext4 partition that I needed more space; cleared it from my Windows install, and then modified the remaining stuff on KDE's partition manager on a live usb.

I'm not experienced at all in this partition management/fixing stuff, so there's a chance I may have done things I wasn't supposed to along the way.

Similar issue: [Recovering ext4 superblocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33284/recovering-ext4-superblocks)

###### Partition structure before (what I remember)

```
|device|type              |
|------|------------------|
|sda1  | ESP Windows      |
|sda2  | MS Reserved      |
|sda3  | Win partition    | 
|sda4  | -(unallocated)-  |
|sda5  | ESP Linux        | *
|sda6  | Swap             | *
|sda7  | Solus Linux      | 
|sda8  | Win recovery env |
```

##### Steps before disaster

- I deleted the partitions inbetween (represented by *) to enable the move, and got to extending Linux.
- I moved **part** of the unallocated space to extend the partition
- I *made sure* to leave no space left after the extended partition
- It took a while and the resize was successful, but ended on an operation error from `e2fsck`: `bad magic number`[...]`superblock invalid`.

##### What I did

After the error, I searched and found through `fdisk` that somehow the partitions got misaligned, reporting "out of disk order" (`sda7` appearing before `sda4`, that sort of thing); showing that some sectors were beginning and ending where they weren't supposed to.

- Researched *bad magic number* and *superblock error*
- Suggestion was to replace the magic number with the backups.
- Tried all with `e2fsck -b {number} /dev/sda7`, but none worked.

I then shifted focus to try and realign the partitions, and found that `fdisk` itself does that, and it worked, placing the Linux partition in the correct place.

- So the sectors are now correct. I checked the others before and after to make sure the realignment didn't affect anything else.

But I'm **still stuck with a resized partition (linux root, ext4) that is not accessible (does not mount), showing up as an unknown filesystem type.**

(Current outputs are at the bottom)

I'm guessing this all happened because resizing made the information about the partition (superblock) change and it didn't update correctly.

---

---

### What can I do to recover?

1. Can I rebuild the superblock information somehow?
2. Backup the contents of the partition in any way before erasing to recreate it correctly?
   I've seen `ddrescue` in passing and it seems to be what I'm looking for
3. What about `testdisk`? It looks promising, but too complex for me to understand atm. Some help here would be nice.

Any replies are very much appreciated.

---

---

#### Outputs

Partition structure after the realignment

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SU650     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2268FBBE-207C-44A8-A784-28F30D837464

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 189430999 189191384 90.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  189431808 192237567   2805760  1.3G  ## temporary fs to avoid mixing up
/dev/sda5  192237568 233375743  41138176 19.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  233375744 234438655   1062912  519M Windows recovery environment
```

(*Yes I have very limited storage, no I don't currently have another option.*)

Trying to mount the partition

```
# mount /dev/sda5 /target     
mount: /target: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Bad magic number error:

```
# e2fsck -v /dev/sda5

e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Comment: If nothing works you could try R-Studio Undelete: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm probably on my own here, I'm going to need it haha